# Why won't the Jquery validation plugin work?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a Jquery validation plugin called bassistance. I have wp_enqueue_script the script. I have loaded Jquery as I understand it's built into wordpress.  I have included the `<script>` tag so that I can  `.validate()` it . I have added the rules by adding `class` to each field.  This is all in one .php script, as I'm just learning. It doesn't seem to work. Please can someone advise? Has the `<style>` tag been used wrongly?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery2' );
    function load_jquery2() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );       }      

    function add_my_css_and_my_js_files(){
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate-min', plugins_url('activate/jquery_validate_min.js', __FILE__ ) );
     }
      add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files");

      <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#calsinput').validate();
    });  
    </script>

function mp_calcs_display() {
return '
<form name="calsinput" action="" method="post" id="calsinput" >
<h1> Process </h1>
<p> operation type always robot </p>
<br> <br>
Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" class="required digits" title="This field is required and must be a no."  >
<br> <br>
Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" class="required digits"  title="This field is required and must be a no.">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate cycle time ">
</form>  ';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `PHP` and `Javascript`.

The part between `<script>` must not be in the `PHP` code, but you could put it in the variable just after `</form>`.

Another way of doing it would be to create a `Javascript` file `myfunctions.js`, putting the code into it and enqueueing it.

The code would be:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery2' );
function load_jquery2() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}      

function add_my_css_and_my_js_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate-min', plugins_url('activate/jquery_validate_min.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files");


function mp_calcs_display() {
return '
<form name="calsinput" action="" method="post" id="calsinput" >
<h1> Process </h1>
<p> operation type always robot </p>
<br> <br>
Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" class="required digits" title="This field is required and must be a no."  >
<br> <br>
Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" class="required digits"  title="This field is required and must be a no.">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate cycle time ">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#calsinput").validate();
    });  
</script>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused. You haven't  used `wp_enqueue_script` on an extra file in your example? You just moved `<script type="text/javascript"> ` further down the page

Comment: No, I went with the simple solution of just outputting it after the `form`, as it is not the best thing to do to include a scriptfile containing just 5 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The Jquery plugin doesn't seem to be working still though. I get the `The plugin generated 655 characters of unexpected output during activation. ` message on the plugin activation page. Is there a way to get a more detailed explanation of errors like this, that you know of? Thank-you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did read that wrong. You have to check that the plugin does not output anything directly (i suppose you call `echo mp_calcs_display();`), but to make it available with a shortcode or a filter on the content.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Should I put `echo` before `mp_calcs_display()` ? mp_calcs_display() is currently in a shortcode to display the form. Thank-you.

Comment: I have used `return` to display the form? Is that OK? Thanks for putting up with me!

Comment: That's okay this way, just be sure your Plugin does not output anything directly.

Comment: Thanks. The Jquery form validation plugin still doesn't seem to be working though.